# Least square method and recursive least square method

Tags: matlab, simulink

I got data which I have to identify using least square method and recursive least square method. Which works fine it'll returns me transfer function for example :

```
           0.002879
 tf=     ----------------------
      z^2 - 1.883 z + 0.8873
```

But the difference between least square method and recursive method is that recursive least square method calculates "transfer function" in steps, estimates are made more precise. So "transfer function" keeps changing. And my question is if I can send that function into the simulink in real time. I know that I can use function set_param. But I can't find way which would show me how "transfer function" in simulink is changing in real time. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are the parameters being re-calculated at each time step, or are they pre-calculated (and hence all known at the start of the simulation)?

Comment: They are re-calculated at each step. I'm using for loop. For example: for n=1:N where N = length(data);

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Why/how/to do what are you using a MATLAB loop if you're using Simulink?

Comment: Because I programmed recursive least square method in matlab but now I have to do same thing in the simulink. And I thought that it would be easier send those parameters from matlab to simulink in real time. Because I don't have that much experience with simulink.

Comment: Do you really mean `real-time`, or do you mean at each time step of a non-real-time simulation?

Comment: I mean in each step

Comment: The Simulink solver - that is the thing that steps your model through time when you press the green _simulate_ button - replaces the MATLAB `for` loop.  Everything within the loop needs to be implemented as connections of Simulink blocks, which may include calling MATLAB code via a [MATLAB Fcn](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block.